# Find the first 1 million record's created date

Tags: soql

I have a requirement to find out the first 1 million record's last created date. As we have about more than two million in the system. As both SOQL queries and offset have less than 10000 limit, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Depends on how you're querying. Rest/Soap API each have a limit of up to 50 million, and read only visualforce pages can access up to 1 million rows. There are ways to get this data.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you for that. I just did a bit selective queries based on CreatedDate and got the approximate date. And the business team is happy with that.

Comment: If you solved your problem, please answer your question as others could benefit from it.

Comment: @RichardN I don't see it as a good resolution though. I just did the approach which is not the accurate number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple way to achieve you goal would just be to export the data using data loader bulk api.