# What is the governor limit on aggregate query rows when using Force.com SOAP or REST APIs?

Tags: query, governorlimits, aggregate

I would like to get the record count from each object (there are fair chances of getting more than 50K records) using a desktop utility and would like to create one CSV file for each object's record count till date.

Comment: I deleted my answer because, after reading the link you sent, I may well be mistaken about API limits. I am surprised though as I thought they'd be bound by the same stuff!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @ReadOnly annotation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_ReadOnly.htm

Find below the test that I have done:

This code is without @ReadOnly annotation:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/AccountCount/*') 
global class  AccountCount_WS {
   @HttpGet
   static webservice Integer getCountAccount(){   
       Integer count = [select count() from Account];
       //just to reach more than 50k because in my sandbox I have arround 17k
       count += [select count() from Account];
       count += [select count() from Account];
       count += [select count() from Account];
       return count;

   }
}
```

and here I get an error when I call the WS:

```
[{
   "errorCode": "APEX_ERROR",
   "message": "System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001\n\nClass.AccountCount_WS.getCountAccount: line 9, column 1"
}]
```

Then I added an @ReadOnly annotation like below

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/AccountCount/*') 
global class  AccountCount_WS {
   @HttpGet
   @ReadOnly
   static webservice Integer getCountAccount(){   
       Integer count = [select count() from Account];
       //just to reach more than 50k because in my sandbox I have arround 17k
       count += [select count() from Account];
       count += [select count() from Account];
       count += [select count() from Account];
       return count;

   }
}
```

The WebService is now able to return a value:

```
68992
```

hope it clarifies

Comment: Hi @Akram, thank you for the response. I wouldn't want writing custom Apex API for this instead looking for online documentation for maximum rows supported by standard REST or SOAP APIs. Unfortunately didn't find in the API documentation but I think I have got what I was looking for in this post. - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118949/find-the-first-1-million-records-created-date/118975